# Cannot change OEM unlocking

Tags: fastboot, bootloader-lock, motorola

I recently installed a Pixel Experience Custom ROM on my phone. After that, for some reason, I decided to block flashing on my phone and this caused message to appear every time I boot my phone: Your Device Is Corrupt,It cant be trusted and will not BOOT visit this link on another device motorola.com/unlockbootloader.

I followed the instructions on this page and it resulted in this: fastboot oem unlock (bootloader) Check 'OEM unlocking' in Android Settings > Developer (bootloader) Options OKAY [ 0.013s] Finished. Total time: 0.013s. but I can't change this setting because I'm not able to enter the system. What can i do in this situation ?

Comment: You never EVER enable OEM unlocking or try to lock the bootloader with a custom firmware... Without being able to boot the system, you can't OEM unlock however I believe you using the wrong command, it is usually "fastboot flashing unlock" in Pixel devices. If it is truly back in a locked and OEM locked state, you can try to flash the stock ROM with the Motorola recovery tool, but I suspect it is now bricked... It would probably be helpful you mentioned the specific device though.

Comment: I think you forgot to link the page?